# Edit USB device driver on Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb

I have a question about changing driver file on Linux. I have an integrated USB device which does not work properly on the Armbian system, but it works on the Unix system which was original part of the device.

Now, I'd like to edit a file `/sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices` - want to change `Driver` from `cdc_acm` to `usbfs`, but when I want to save changes, there is an error message: `E667: Fsync failed. Original file may be lost or damaged`. I have also set the permissions to 777 and run editor as root but that doesn't help either.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot edit file /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices to force linux kernel to use another driver. This is read-only file generated by the kernel and is only for informing user-space tools.

Type of the driver is selected by the kernel basing on USB descriptors which are presented by USB device.

Comment: Thank you. But what would be the proper way to change the information?

Comment: It depends if you have access to sources of the access to sources of the USB device. If yes - change it in sources. If not and your USB device is Linux - maybe there is some module parameter, which allows you to change type of the USB device. I guess you may also change sources of the USB host (Linux) and change in recognition procedure the driver the linux loads - but I didn't do it and I only guess that it is possible.